# Detect a real world object using ARKit and SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I am new with ARKit and SceneKit frameworks and I want to know if it's possible to detect real world object like a door a wall or something.

For example is it possible to detect an object's collision with a door or any other real world objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ARKit` can detect planes, but right now only horizontal ones, see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424070/5815048).
Other detections are not part of `ARKit`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to do that with SceneKit ? Or we can only detect collision between two virtual objects in the scenekit  ?

Comment: SceneKit is a game engine and only works with virtual objects. `ARKit` is essentially a bridge between the real world and the virtual objects used in SceneKit. But there are a number of different AR frameworks out there ([Vuforia](https://www.vuforia.com) beeing the biggest one I know) that offer a lot of additional features over `ARKit`